# Trigger recurring email SP2013 WF2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am using SP2013, with Workflow 2010. How can I trigger weekly email when a field doesn't meet condition? This is what I have so far: Only the first email is triggered.

[image: Workflow]

I've tried http://sharepoint713.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-send.html
and
https://kmlsp.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/more-on-calendar-reminder-4-steps-to-create-reminder-workflow-in-sharepoint-calendar/

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep sending the reminder Email, you will need to add a loop which is not available in 2010 workflow. The available option will be using Retention policy which has options to set recurrence.

A reference for you:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0e7577e-adb6-4e63-81ab-fe037dedcd33/forum-faq-sharepoint-workflow-weekly-reminder?forum=sharepointgeneral